# Error : Xcode 4.6.3 - Method dragFromToForDuration does not work at all

Tags: javascript, ipad, ios-ui-automation, unrecognized-selector

I use method `dragFromToForDuration` to test my app on iPad. This method intends to tap and hold then drag an image to another location on the iPad's screen. I define exactly location of both the image and the targeted area. However, implementing this method generates an error:

```
target.dragFromToForDuration({x:startCoord.x, y:startCoord.y}, {x:finishCoord.x, y:finishCoord.y}, {duration:3});
```

> [_NSCFDictionary doubleValue] : unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1f83e5d0

**Update:**
If I remove the word "duration" and the code became:
    target.dragFromToForDuration({x:startCoord.x, y:startCoord.y}, {x:finishCoord.x, y:finishCoord.y}, 3);

With this changing, xcode does not generate any error/warning and go through it without any action on the screen.
Anyone encountered this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This function works well after modifying the startPoint and endPoint of target. I did not see this fault but my fellow did. :)